# MongoDB: $match on today's date + $in

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to figure out (what should be..) a simple query.   In my document, I have the field:

```
date_array : {15 : 2023-01-03T00:00:00.000+00:00, 
              16: 2023-01-04T00:00:00.000+00:00,
              17 : 2023-01-05T00:00:00.000+00:00}
```

I am simply trying to query on `{$in: todays_date}`

For example:

```
{
  date_array : {$in : [new Date("<YYYY-mm-dd>")]},  #syntax error in the date function
}
```

or

```
{
  date_array : {$in : [new Date()]},  # includes the current time, which doesn't work
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: No need for `$in` in this case (looking for a specific item). You can format the date in your code before inserting it to the query. You can also truncate it inside the query, but I don't see why...

Comment: this is all being done in the aggregation pipeline builder in Compass though for whatever thats worth.   so I'm not sure how to format the date via code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you realy want to do it without a code, you can do:

```
db.collection.find(
  {$expr: [{$in: [{$dateTrunc: {date: "$$NOW", unit: "day"}}, "$date_array"]}]}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/goxq86foy-R)

Comment: thanks for that.  When I try to adapt it to the aggregation pipline builder, it gives me a "cannot nest $ under $in" error.   I did:  date_array: {$in: [{$dateTrunc: 
   {date: "$$NOW", unit: "day"}}]}

Comment: Further - when I try to add in the $expr part, that gives me an "Unexpected token" error.

Comment: wait, go it!  user error on my part. thanks!